# Brigtness cannot be changed

Tags: xubuntu, acer

I have an Acer Aspire v5-573. I have to decrease brightness every time I switch on my PC. When switching the laptop on again, brightness becomes high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me personally, for my laptop (an old Dell), I use Redshift because I am unable to adjust the brightness (something about old technology so no dimming via function commands). Redshift is in Ubuntu Software. I absolutely adore it!

I have never had it where mine was dim then bright upon open/close of the lid. Interesting issue. I wonder if Redshift will resolve that for you.

jth

Comment: Not that useful? Well, based on his tag, I am assuming he is running Xubuntu. But which version? You see, there is a guy named Norbert that has a ppa... let me find it, I have the bookmark somewhere... ... ...

Gah, I keep forgetting to hit Shift + Enter. Sorry.

Anywho, here is the info for what I use on an old Acer v3 on Linux Mint 14.10. After this version though I cannot find anything like this if he is beyond that version: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-mint-brightness-settings/

I guess my Redshift mention wasn't helpful, but it was at least help-ish considering it works for me.